# How to change phantom "inherited" ACE on existing folder?

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, acl

I unjoined my PC from a Windows domain and converted my profile from domain to local using ForensIT's ProfWiz. Now some apps are giving me an "Access Denied" error on their `ProgramData` folders. These folders have an "inherited" ACE giving full control to my old domain account SID, but the parent folder has no corresponding ACE for the SID, just a `CREATOR OWNER` ACE, which I'm guessing is responsible for the child ACE.

How do I change the child ACE's SID to that of my local account, or more generally, how do you change an "inherited" ACE which is not in the parent? I know I can just add a new ACE for my local account, that is *not* what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

If the folder doesn't need any explicit ACEs, only inherited ones, you can run `icacls /reset` on it. The program will set an empty ACL, and doing so will recalculate the inherited ACL.

I'm not sure about any tools which would allow direct editing of individual inherited ACEs. (As far as I know, this would be completely possible on a technical level, but most ACL editors just deliberately not allow editing of ACEs with the inherited flag.)

Comment: It's not an explicit ACE, which is the mystery! It's a special ACE that is inherited *and* explicit at the same time, created by the ```CREATOR OWNER``` ACE in the parent folder.

Comment: I don't see anything particularly mysterious about that. All inherited ACEs _are_ explicitly stored in the object's ACL – they aren't just looked up from the parent at time of access, they're actually copied from the parent whenever the ACL is set. So when the parent ACL changes (or when the object [moves under a different parent](http://web.archive.org/web/20070226212923if_/http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/24/717181.aspx)), an explicit step is needed to recalculate the child's ACL, i.e. to discard all inherited ACEs and copy in new ones.

Comment: (It just looks seamless because the [default Windows-provided functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/automatic-propagation-of-inheritable-aces) for changing an ACL will automatically re-apply all child ACLs.)

Comment: It's a mystery because the child ACE is for `domain\user` with `full control` and is inherited, but the parent has no explicit ACE for `domain\user`, only for `CREATOR OWNER`; so when the folder was created under my old `domain\user` account, Windows created that ACE from the `CREATOR OWNER` template. I could change the security principal to my new local account for explicit ACE's using SetACL Studio, but this one is greyed out.